# Getting data from multiple column as one in SQL Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server and I have a table with columns:

`Id, State1, State2, State3, City1, City2, City3, Street1, Street2, Street3`.

Where State1, City1, Street1 are a "triple".

I need to select all data from  the table where

`(State1 = xyz, City1 = xyzv, Street1 = abcd) or (State2 = xyz....)`

and show it like that: `State1 as State/State2 as State` -> the same name for each triple columns.

I need to say that each triple in row is unique or null. So there can be 1,2,3 unique addresses in row.

How can I do it? Now I have something like that, but there is an

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
>   Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. error.

```
    select ds.Data as Data, 
    case 
    when ds.Gmina1 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc1 = @CityName and ds.Street1 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber1 = @LocalNumber then (select ds.Gmina1 as Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc1 as Miasto, ds.Street1 as Ulica, ds.LocalNumber1 from Dostawy)
    when ds.Gmina2 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc2 = @CityName and ds.Street2 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber2 = @LocalNumber then (select ds.Gmina2 as Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc2 as Miasto, ds.Street2 as Ulica, ds.LocalNumber2 from Dostawy)
    when ds.Gmina2 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc3 = @CityName and ds.Street3 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber3 = @LocalNumber then (select ds.Gmina3 as Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc3 as Miasto, ds.Street3 as Ulica, ds.LocalNumber3 from Dostawy)
    else null
    end
  from dbo.Dostawy as ds
```

Comment: `I need to select all data from the table **where**...` - perhaps it's better to put those conditions into `WHERE` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible approach to get your resultset is to use `UNION ALL` and appropriate `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT ds.Data AS Data, ds.Gmina1 AS Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc1 AS Miasto, ds.Street1 AS Ulica, ds.LocalNumber1 AS LocalNumber
FROM Dostawy ds
WHERE
    ds.Gmina1 = @StateName AND
    ds.Miejscowosc1 = @CityName AND
    ds.Street1 = @StreetName AND 
    ds.LocalNumber1 = @LocalNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT ds.Data AS Data, ds.Gmina2 AS Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc2 AS Miasto, ds.Street2 AS Ulica, ds.LocalNumber2 AS LocalNumber 
FROM Dostawy ds
WHERE
    ds.Gmina2 = @StateName AND
    ds.Miejscowosc2 = @CityName AND
    ds.Street2 = @StreetName AND 
    ds.LocalNumber2 = @LocalNumber
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    ds.Data AS Data, ds.Gmina3 AS Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc3 AS Miasto, ds.Street3 AS Ulica, ds.LocalNumber3 AS LocalNumber 
FROM Dostawy ds
WHERE 
    ds.Gmina2 = @StateName AND
    ds.Miejscowosc3 = @CityName AND
    ds.Street3 = @StreetName AND 
    ds.LocalNumber3 = @LocalNumber
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the error is the below expression in each THEN block. As error explains, you cannot have multiple columns, so you should select only one.

```
(select ds.Gmina1 as Gmina, ds.Miejscowosc1 as Miasto, ds.Street1 as Ulica, ds.LocalNumber1 from Dostawy)
```

Also you need not to have another SELECT sub query to get the value for that one column, the below query should work.

```
select ds.Data as Data, 
    case 
    when ds.Gmina1 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc1 = @CityName and ds.Street1 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber1 = @LocalNumber then ds.Gmina1
    when ds.Gmina2 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc2 = @CityName and ds.Street2 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber2 = @LocalNumber then ds.Gmina2
    when ds.Gmina2 = @StateName and ds.Miejscowosc3 = @CityName and ds.Street3 = @StreetName and ds.LocalNumber3 = @LocalNumber then ds.Gmina3
    else null
    end as Gmina
  from dbo.Dostawy as ds
```